# Spring Beans Created Multiple Times

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I am just new to Spring and facing a design problem. The problem is i have a maven multiple module projects. Project Structures goes as follows.

module-backoffice  - Packaging(war)

module-ws        -   Packaging(war)

module-dao      - Packaging(jar)

module-shared     -  Packaging(jar)

In "module shared "all my service class and in "module-dao" all dao related codes exists. 
module-shared and module-dao is in the build path of module-backoffice and module-ws.

Now Problem is when i run module-backoffice war and module-ws war Spring creates two instance of Service class beans and dao class beans.

What should i do so that one instance of service class and dao class will be created and shared among multiple war ? Please help. Thanks you.

Code in Module-Shared: Below  is Service factory class

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Services {

@Autowired
private List<Service> services;

private static final Map<Class<?>, Service> serviceCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, Service>();


@PostConstruct
public void initServiceCache() {
    services.forEach(service -> serviceCache.put(service.getClass(), service));
    services = null;
}

public static Bootstrap bootstrap() {
    return (Bootstrap) serviceCache.get(Bootstrap.class);
}
```

And the service class is :

```
@Component
public class Bootstrap implements Service {

public Bootstrap() {
    System.out.println("Bootstrap");
  }
}
```

When i run tomcat deploying two wars then in console two times "Bootstrap" printed. How do i restrict that.?

Comment: How do you get to know that services are creating twice? And post your configuration on war files.

Comment: I should initialize the dependencies two time as you running two difference wars. Please so share your configurations.

Comment: Please have a look in my code. I have edited

Comment: You are deploying 2 applications so you will get 2 instances of the beans.

Comment: Can i do something so that one instance will be shared

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of web container like tomcat is to able to run applications independently so they can be started and stopped without affecting each other. In case you think there can be multiple future applications will also require the same service, you can make a separate application and expose an API for the operations.